# how do i pass data between views in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have two views. One is a left nav that has a list of items the other is the main screen that I need to change depending on which item you select.

here is the toggle function that I change the "name" I'm trying to update

```
onToggleFilter(checked) {
    let d = this.props.data
    this.setProjectName(d.id)
    //console.log("name" + d.id)
    d.onFilter = checked
    if( d.children && d.children.length > 0 ) {
        d.children.forEach( item => {
            item.onFilter = checked
        })
    }
    this.setState({ selected: checked })
    if( this.props.onFilterChanged ) {
        this.props.onFilterChanged(checked)     
    }
}

setProjectName (data){
    console.log ("name" + data)
    let projectName = data

}
```

that consoles out to name Remarkable (thats one of the projects on the left nav)

Somehow I need to pass that projectName to another component. I'm new to react and I'm sure its something simple but from reading the documentation I'm a little stuck.

OK I think I know how to do the first part:

I have a data service file that has this function

```
getNavInfo (){


        _instance.navData = navArray

        console.log ("instance hit"+ navArray)

    }
```

This picks up on an array of items that is set elsewhere in the file

Here is the call on the other component

```
getDataNav ()

    {
        let d = this.dataService.getNavInfo()
        console.log ("d here" + d)
    }
```

Dataservice is the other component.

When I do this though

```
this.dataService.getNavInfo().then(this.getDataNav)

getDataNav (data)

    {
            console.log ("d here" + data);
    }
```

Its telling me that this is undefined  -

```
this.dataService.getNavInfo().then(this.getDataNav)
```

Comment: You can only pass data between parent-children, not between children.

Comment: do i need to do something like this? https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html not sure how that works...

Comment: Yes. In your case, it'll probably easier for the container that contains the two view components to manage the state, and pass the state and function as props to them. If things get's complicated, you might want to look into things like [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux) to manage the state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so here is how I did it. Keep in mind I know that I need to use something like redux to better track and manage state but for now I just wanted a way to refresh the data when someone clicked on a project in the left nav:

This is from the event call when someone clicks on a project -

```
this.dataService.newProjectSelected(d.id)
```

This is from the constructor on the view I'm trying to update -

```
this.dataService.subscribeToProjectUpdate(this.newDataReceived.bind(this))
newDataReceived(projectId) {
    console.log(projectId)
    if( !projectId ) {
        return
    }
```

These are calls to the functions that take the data the display the data -

```
    this.dataService.defect(projectId).then(this.processDataDefect)
    this.dataService.demand(projectId).then(this.processDataDemand)
    this.dataService.effort(projectId).then(this.processDataEffort)
    this.dataService.chartLegend(projectId).then(this.proccessDataLegend)
    this.dataService.projectname(projectId).then(this.proccessDataProjectName)
}
```

These are in the data service files that actually make the api calls -

```
newProjectSelected(projectId) {
        this.projectCallbacks.map(callback => callback(projectId))
    }

    subscribeToProjectUpdate(callback) {
        if( !this.projectCallbacks ) {
            this.projectCallbacks = new Array()
        }

        // Todo make sure we only add it once
        this.projectCallbacks.push(callback)
    }
```

I know its a little hacky but it was one of those "I need something now" type of things we have all come across.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a App.js as parent of LeftNav, and MainScreen component. Pass the state of parent down to children as props.

```
<App>
  <LeftNav selected={this.state.projectName} handleToggle={ //... when item been clicked, change projectName in state of App }>
  <MainScreen projectName={this.state.projectName}>
</App>
```

... Replace projectName with your id or anything you like

Comment: so here is a way i think might work the only problem is that the view is not refreshing.. so I'm using local storage and when the use clicks the nav it updates the id in local storage and calls the page..but the page doesn't seem to refresh ;

Comment: localStorage.setItem('ticker', JSON.stringify(d.id));
  location.href = '/#/cfd/'